# OS X Time Machine keeps getting disabled

Tags: macos, time-machine

For some reason my Time Machine keeps getting disabled in OS X. Every time I look at it, it's disabled. Why would this happen? It is an office Time Machine server I am backing up to and only when I am at work, but the next day when I return to work with my MacBook Pro it is disabled again. How can I see why it is disabling?

Comment: Please add screenshots to your question to help us better understand your frustration.

Comment: Not much to screenshot. Time machine is off.

Comment: By "off" do you mean "the switch is greyed-out" or "the switch is off"?

Comment: Switch is off every time I go into there.

Comment: Have you tried turning the switch on or does it ask you to select a backup disk?

Comment: I can turn it on and run backups but then the next day it is back to off. Not sure why

Comment: I will look into this and see what I can find. In the meantime, do have a look at Console and see what `backupd` reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Viscosity as my VPN and by default it disables time machine upon connecting to the VPN. It is pretty much always on so that is why it seemed to be disabled all the time. I was able to fix this by disabling the option to disable time machine when connected to the VPN.